# What data structures / algorithm do dating apps use for finding proximate people?

Tags: database, algorithm, elasticsearch, data-structures, bigdata

Some dating apps based on proximate localization have hundreds of millions of users, they all have a dynamic localization.

Every time a user enters the application, it will find many users close to him and it happens very fast.
This means that the application (Theoretically) has to compare the location of the current user with the hundred of millions of other users.

I thought about indexing every latitude with 5 decimal digit, which is accurate to the 1 meter, this will represent (I think) few millions of indexes.
These indexes could be Elasticsearch indexes.

Is this the way to use a technology like Elasticsearch?
What would be a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index

Comment: @Mat Thanks! Interesting! I'll have a look